# Convert string with hex ASCII codes to characters

Tags: ruby, ascii

I have a string containing hex code values of ASCII characters, e.g. `"666f6f626172"`. I want to convert it to the corresponding string (`"foobar"`).

This is working but ugly:

```
"666f6f626172".scan(/../).map(&:hex).map(&:chr).join # => "foobar"
```

Is there a better (more concise) way? Could `unpack` be helpful somehow?

Comment: Like `["666f6f626172"].pack('H*')`?

Comment: @Stefan. Yes, like that. Could you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use [`Array#pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-pack):

```
["666f6f626172"].pack('H*')
#=> "foobar"
```

`H` is the directive for a hex string (high nibble first).

Comment: `pack`/`unpack` will remain a mystery to me forever.

Answer (score 23):

Stefan has nailed it, but here's an alternative you may want to tuck away for another time and place:

```
"666f6f626172".gsub(/../) { |pair| pair.hex.chr } # => "foobar"
```